# mathcad coeffs command, find coefficient of each variable at one shot

Tags: coefficients, mathcad

I have a simple function:

```
w(x) := C1*cos(x)+C2*sin(x)+C3*cosh(x)+C4*sinh(x)
```

I evaluate this at x=L and get:

```
C1*cos(L)+C2*sin(L)+C3*cosh(L)+C4*sinh(L)
```

Sometimes my equations are really long and complicated. I want to find coefficient of each C's such as:

```
coeffs C1: cos(L)
coeffs C2: sin(L)
coeffs C3: cosh(L)
coeffs C4: sinh(L)
```

However, I only get coefficient of one variable at a time. I would like to find all the coefficients of variable.

When I add multiple coeffs, it does not show the coefficients but shows something different such as:

```
({2,1},{1,1})
```

Is there a way to find all the coefficients at one shot?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could post a little more about what you expect to get?  Can you attach a worksheet with an example?

The `({2,1},{1,1})` expression you are seeing is Mathcad's default display for a nested array (that is, an array that contains other arrays).  To show the array in full:

In Mathcad 15 (or lower), double click on the result (ie, `({2,1},{1,1})`) and you should see the Results dialog box.  Select the Display Options tab, select Matrix from the 'Matrix display style' drop-down menu, tick 'Expand nested arrays' and click OK.   This should show you the full array.